# Facebook like button outputting but hiding like count

Tags: jquery, css, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Facebook like buttons are used in a number of locations throughout http://www.daysoftheyear.com/, implemented via a robust XFBML setup, and have historically worked perfectly well.

As of yesterday (in line with no discernable changes that I'm aware of), it seems that an inline style of 'visibility: hidden' is being programatically applied to the container div of the 'count' element of the like button. If you use firebug, you can clearly see the this element is present and functioning (e.g., correct count, 'liking' increments count, etc), however, the element is simply invisible.

I'm struggling to understand why this may be, and/or to fix the symptoms.

Does anybody have an understanding of why this may be occuring, or alternatively, a jQuery-based solution to forcibly remove the inline attribute once the iframe content has loaded? Is the latter even feasible (no matter how hacky/clunky)?

Additionally, the 'like' button in the top right, which references a Facebook URL (the site's Facebook page), works correctly - however this uses a different type of like button which outputs different markup, leading me to believe that the problem is not in which case nescessarily to do with the targeting of the like...

Screenshot attached.
[image]

Comment: This issue has been [logged](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20213) with Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have resolved itself; suspect bug at Facebook's end?